# GitLab CI SAST for Android : Job mobsf-android-sast failed

Tags: android, gitlab-ci

I got an error with the job mobsf-android-sast, do i miss some configurations for mobsf?

**Log:**

```
$ /analyzer run
[INFO] [MobSF] [2022-06-17T14:02:46Z] ▶ GitLab MobSF analyzer v3.0.0
......
......
[INFO] [MobSF] [2022-06-17T14:02:49Z] ▶ Zipping: keystore.properties
[INFO] [MobSF] [2022-06-17T14:02:49Z] ▶ Zipping: sonar-project.properties
[FATA] [MobSF] [2022-06-17T14:02:49Z] ▶ failed to upload archive to mobsf: error requesting scan: Post "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/upload": dial tcp [::1]:8000: connect: connection refused
Uploading artifacts for failed job
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: gl-sast-report.json: no matching files    
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
include:
  - template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml

variables:
  SAST_EXPERIMENTAL_FEATURES: "true"

sast:
  stage: test
```

Answer (score 0):

```
variables:
  SAST_EXPERIMENTAL_FEATURES: "true"
  DS_DISABLE_DIND: "true"

sast:
      stage: test
      dependencies:
        - build
      artifacts:
        reports:
          sast: gl-sast-report.json
        paths:
          - gl-sast-report.json
      tags:
        - docker
```

try this one